# Autoinstall modules when running the Node Webkit build

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I created a Node webkit app and created the run files using [NW-Builder](https://github.com/nwjs/nw-builder).
The app size is very large(200MB) because of the modules that were used.
Is it possible to create an installer that downloads the dependencies required so that the app size remains low.

Answer (score 0):

you do understand that the app size will eventually be the same, right? the client will have to download it anyway. This is not a common approach as you will have to handle any errors downloading the modules on the client instead of doing so only once when building the app.

Another issue is that [node module manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm) is required to to download the modules.

Instead, allow users to download the entire package including all modules, but compress the app to make it smaller.

Comment: yeah...compressed it along with the modules.
But just for information, is it possible to create an installer?